# jquery mobile block execution or exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

There are some very interesting questions here for stopping execution and most of these relate to pausing for a certain time before something else is allowed to occur.

I have a slightly different scenario in my jquery mobile 1.3.2 with the following function which adds an event to user's calendar.

```
    function addToMyCal(typ,id)
    {
        loginReq();
        addToUsrCal(window.wh2usr,"spscId",id);
    }
    // login required
    function loginReq()
    {
         // check cookie
        if (! loginCheck())
            $('#popupLogin').popup('open')
    }
```

I observe that, if a user is not logged in, then the login popup is shown but it does not pause to get user credentials. Instead the login popup is displayed, addToUsrCal() is called right away, which fails because there is no user information.

So how do I 1) either wait till user provides credentials without a timeout or 2) allow user to cancel the login and return back to where they were on the site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `$('#popupLogin').popup` doesn't wait for any user interaction - it just displays the popup and immediately returns. Then the `loginReq` function is finished and returns to the caller, `addToMyCal`. From there, the next line in `addToMyCal` is executed - the call to `addToUsrCal`.

If you want to call `addToUsrCal` only after some user input, then you'll need to move that function call to a callback function - probably tied to the submit action on a form or the click action of a submit button (these presumably already exist in your popup's content).

Similarly, you can add a callback to a cancel button in the popup that will close the popup (using a call to `$('#popupLogin').popup("close")`.